# Loops are not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have simple code for toggle up and down that is working on other browser except IE, I think because I'm using `forEach`, but I'm not sure if that's the cause. How to fix this?

```js
const dropWrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");

dropWrapper.forEach(function (el) {

    let drop = el.querySelector(".dropdown-company-trust");
    let dropContainer = el.querySelector("#myDropdown");
    let arrow = el.querySelector(".jsArrow");

    drop.addEventListener("click", function () {
        dropContainer.classList.toggle("show");
        arrow.classList.toggle("jsArrowUp");
    })

})
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Are you sure it's the forEach that's failing and now the `querySelectorAll`? Also, specifically which browser?

Comment: Maybe the problem is `const`? It's only supported in IE11. The browser's console should tell you where the error is.

Comment: @kmgt I don't get any errors

Comment: @TylerRoper I'm checking on EI version 11

Comment: @TKoL It seems my code is working and doesn't get any error, so I assume it's more forEach or looping problem, I'm checking on EI version 11

Comment: @Barmar Tried to use let, but still doesn't work, the problem I don't see any error

Comment: console.log() statements or debugger and see what fails

Comment: I have an error: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'.

Comment: @kmgt ohh right, yes just saw it, Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach', so I can't use forEach?

Comment: @kmgt Good catch! My initial comment was mistaken. As you've pointed out in your answer, OP is using `NodeList.forEach`, which is *not* supported. My initial comment referred, incorrectly, to `Array.forEach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach`is supported in Internet Explorer BUT not for iterating over a `NodelList`:

```
NodeList.forEach(callback[, thisArg]);
```

You can find the browser compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility)

To get `foreEach` work in Internet Explorer use a polyfill. It sets the `NodeList.foreEach`equal to `Array.foreEach`.

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}

var dropWrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");

dropWrapper.forEach(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Can you use `Array.from` ?

Comment: Looks like you can't even `array.from` it... But there's a quick polyfill for that one I'm sure.

Comment: So I can't use forEach in internet explorer, how to fix this?

Comment: @Udzzzz Use a `for` loop.

Comment: Or the polyfill in MDN.

Comment: @kmgt, thanks it's working if I add the condition nodelist, I thought before we need to add Array.from to make it work, but it seems change now

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` isn't available for `NodeList`, so you can write it the old-fashioned way with a `for` loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < dropWrapper.length; i++) {
    let el = dropWrapper[i];
    let drop = el.querySelector(".dropdown-company-trust");
    let dropContainer = el.querySelector("#myDropdown");
    let arrow = el.querySelector(".jsArrow");

    drop.addEventListener("click", function () {
        dropContainer.classList.toggle("show");
        arrow.classList.toggle("jsArrowUp");
    })
}
```